# Flexbox - image columns with fixed margins: how to get even image widths

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a design with images in columns with a fixed margin (or gap) between them.
Right now the columns have margins, and because the total margin is different for each column (since there is no left margin on the first column and no right margin on the last), the width of each column image becomes different, causing the height to be different on the middle images.
[image]

I tried to divide the margin so that each column uses the same total amount of margin (which seems instinctively over complicated) . I can get that to work, but it doesn't work for 3 columns. You can't make three columns use the same amount of margin I think.

I know there is some "gap" property in css grid, but how do I solve it in flexbox?

See my example code here:  [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-field-e57b8?file=/src/App.vue)

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <div>
          <img
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633357337538-83612701c7a9?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <div>
          <img
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633357337538-83612701c7a9?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <div>
          <img
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633357337538-83612701c7a9?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <div>
          <img
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633357337538-83612701c7a9?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {},
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
#app {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
  img {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}
.col-3 {
  flex: 0 1 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  /* width:25%; */
  > div {
    /* margin-right:25px; */
  }
  &:first-child > div {
    margin-right: 12.5px;
  }
  &:nth-child(2) > div {
    margin-right: 12.5px;
    margin-left: 12.5px;
  }
  &:nth-child(3) > div {
    margin-right: 12.5px;
    margin-left: 12.5px;
  }
  &:last-child > div {
    margin-left: 12.5px;
  }
}
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You are changing the margins on your divs inside the columns. So each column get's smaller, some more and some less. That's why your images get also smaller, some more, some less.

Comment: @Prince Cause I see the same confusion everywhere.

Comment: @Rob if we're bringing specs into this, `img` is a "void element" and the "self-closing slash" is valid but non-functional: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-start-tag

Comment: @worc Yes, it's valid, but no HTML specification calls for its use. A void element is a void element with or without the slash. So the slash does nothing, has no meaning, and browsers are instructed to ignore it. So using it is pointless.

Comment: @Prince Now that I see it, I don't think I'm saying anything different than Rob. "does not use" and "does not need" is the same thing as "valid but non-functional."

Comment: @worc Nothing is more important than following the specification. Anything else is unreliable. Also for your edification: http://www.colorglare.com/2014/02/03/to-close-or-not-to-close.html

Comment: @Rob the spec is written so that people can communicate effectively. why else would they leave a non-functioning slash as valid? it helps communicate that the tag and its attributes are complete and the author intended to close that tag and write no nested elements.

Comment: @worc If one doesn't know it's self-closing, how does one know to add the closing slash? Again, the slash is meaningless and ignored by browsers and unspecified for each tag/element. What's the point?

Comment: @Rob the point is that code is read by **people**. and, i guess it bears repeating, it communicates intent to close the tag and nest no elements.

Comment: @worc Again, if you do not know the tag is closed, how do you know to add the slash? This is beyond unreasonable and I won't respond anymore.

Comment: @Rob the *author* knows that the tag is closed. and the slash reinforces that to anyone reading the source. this optional punctuation is allowed by the spec. it's perfectly reasonable, even if essentially every runtime out there doesn't care.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I realise now that you're looking for a solution using flex rather than css grid. The other answer provides some options there. If you do want to use grid though this approach is handy as your widths will be automatically calculated with whatever gap you choose.

Use `display:grid`, and set your container to have four columns with one fractional unit for each column, and a `column-gap` of the gap you want.

The gap below the image is caused because by default images are inline elements, so they sit with the baseline of text. If you set your images to `display:block` the gap will disappear.

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 12px;
  column-gap: 12px;
  border:3px solid yellow;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-3 img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633357337538-83612701c7a9?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633357337538-83612701c7a9?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633357337538-83612701c7a9?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633357337538-83612701c7a9?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate it as an alternative, it might be the best optional solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the code using flexbox and made a little change to your HTML code

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633357337538-83612701c7a9?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80"
        />
      </div>

      <div>
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633357337538-83612701c7a9?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80"
        />
      </div>

      <div>
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633357337538-83612701c7a9?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80"
        />
      </div>

      <div>
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633357337538-83612701c7a9?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

    <style lang="scss">
    body {
      margin: 0;
      .row {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: space-between;
        div {
          padding: 0 10px;
          &:nth-child(1) {
            padding-left: 0;
          }
          &:nth-last-child(1) {
            padding-right: 0;
          }
          img {
            width: 100%;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: Oops.. You forgot to add your explanation for you answer

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox does have a [`gap` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container#properties_that_control_alignment) that will space your items evenly and won't create empty spaces on the right or left. But, based on the code sample you shared, I think your issue is a combination of a couple of things:

1. Your middle two containers are smaller than your outer two containers because of their extra margin
2. Your images are set to take the full width of their containers

Because the middle two containers are smaller—and the images are preserving their aspect ratio—you get images that are both narrower *and shorter*.

If you strip everything down to just using `gap`, I think you'll be a lot closer to what you're trying to accomplish:

```css
.flexbox {
  background-color: #ace;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  gap: 8px;
  width: 800px;
}

.container {
  flex: 0 1 25%;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 25%;
}

img.full-width {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="container">
    <img class="full-width" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" />
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img class="full-width" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" />
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img class="full-width" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" />
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img class="full-width" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" />
  </div>
</div>
```